# Accordion widget is not working on filter nav

Tags: jquery, magento2.2.2

I am on Magento 2.2 and trying to use the accordion widget as below:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html

```
<dl class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list">
    <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title">Base Material</dt>
    <dd class="filter-options-content">
        <ol class="items">
            <li class="item">
                <a href="http://shop.mz-at.de.orange.imi.local/products/base_material-polyester.html">
                    Polyester <span class="count">1<span class="filter-count-label">
                             item</span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="http://shop.mz-at.de.orange.imi.local/products/base_material-styroldivinylbenzol.html">
                    Styroldivinylbenzol <span class="count">6<span class="filter-count-label">
                             items</span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </dd>
    <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title">Bed Mass [mg]</dt>
    <dd class="filter-options-content">
        <div class="range-attribute-filter clearfix">
            <div id="slider-bed_mass_in_mg-range"></div>
            <div class="bed_mass_in_mg-range range">
                <div class="">
                    <input id="bed_mass_in_mg-from" name="bed_mass_in_mg-from"> -
                    <input id="bed_mass_in_mg-to" name="bed_mass_in_mg-to"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
{ "*": { "niksSlider": {
    "urlTemplate": "http://shop.mz-at.de.orange.imi.local/products/bed_mass_in_mg-{{from}}_{{to}}.html",
    "code": "bed_mass_in_mg",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 0,
    "from": 0,
    "to": 0} } }

        </script>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Initialization:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#narrow-by-list": {
            "accordion": {
                "header": "dt",
                "content": "dd",
                "trigger": "dt"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But just nothing seems to happen - no Javascript errors in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization has to happen like this: header was the wrong array key - collapsible element is to be the "dt"

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
    "#narrow-by-list": {
        "accordion": {
            "collapsibleElement" : "dt",
            "content": "dd",
            "trigger": "dt"
        }
    }
    }
</script>
```

The example on the devdocs makes more sense with knowing those default settings:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/web/mage/tabs.js#L20

Answer (score 0):

**The following solution is provided for future reference purposes.** If you've encountered issues with collapsible navigation in Magento 2, this solution might be helpful for similar scenarios.

**First of all check the parent theme of your custom theme you are using?**

**If you are using blank parent theme then It does not have this functionality.**

**Luma theme having this feature.**

**1. Locate the View File in Luma Theme:** The file responsible for rendering the layered navigation in the Luma theme is view.phtml, typically found in the following directory:

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml
```

**2. Copy View File to Custom Theme:** If your custom theme doesn’t have a view.phtml file in the same location, copying the view.phtml file from the Luma theme to your custom theme can be a quick solution.

**3. Compare and Modify:** If you already have a view.phtml file in your custom theme, compare it with the one from Luma. Identify the differences, especially in the JavaScript and HTML structure related to collapsible navigation, and integrate those changes into your custom theme’s file.

Comment: I already found the solution and forgot to accept my answer. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for comment, I forget to add the note at top that I've included the solution for future reference. This might assist others encountering similar issues with collapsible navigation.